# htaccess doesn't removing php extensions

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a php project running. I am running my project on `localhost`. I want to remove php extensions from url in addressbar. I try several htaccess scripts but none worked some shows 404 not found error or doesn't work at all.
directory where my php project is `D:\VertrigoServ\www\gotmation` 
I am using this htaccess script

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php[\s?] [NC]
# RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
 RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L] 

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/gta/$1.php -f
# RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /gta/$1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I am newbie php programmer doesn't have much experience of this stuff. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

This must work... you might have any other issues... do you have permitted .htaccess in apache config file???

Comment: it's not removing php extension right now it's like

Comment: This results in a 500 error if you try to go to `/xxxxx` where `/xxxxx.php` doesn't exist.

Comment: no error but it shows like `http://localhost//gotmation/about_us.php` and off-course it I manually edit url like `http://localhost//gotmation/about_us` it works too. I want it to happen automatically. thanks @Valency

Comment: RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)\.php   this will force removal of .php add this just below RewriteEngine On

Comment: After that line... add this as well ...   RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301] ..... see the edited answer

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.+)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

These rules need to be in your *document root*.

Comment: dude after using this `404 not found error` problem

Comment: Not Found

The requested URL /gotmation/contacts-us was not found on this server

Comment: @Jarvish THe htaccess file is in `/` and `/gotmation/contacts-us.php` exists? Have you cleared your cache? These rules [work perfectly fine for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eWE62.png)